# Array of random locations - moment-timezone.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, momentjs, moment-timezone

How can I find a random location based on the [moment-timezone.js](https://momentjs.com/timezone/)? I want to show a new location every time you refresh the page.

Current code:

```
<hero>
    <div id="hover">
    <h2>Present time</h2>
    <div id="time"></div>
    </div>
</hero>

<script>

(function clock() {
  var now = moment().format('lll'); //local time

  /*
  I want many of these..
  moment.tz("Europe/Berlin").format('lll');
  */

  var time = document.getElementById('time');
  time.innerHTML = now;

  setInterval(clock, 1000);
})();

</script>
```

Comment: Current code: https://hastebin.com/ejayuyexav.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose a random timezone from [all available timezones](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/getting-zone-names/):

```js
const timezones = moment.tz.names();
const randTimezone = timezones[Math.floor(Math.random() * timezones.length)];
const now = moment.tz(randTimezone).format('lll');

document.write(randTimezone, '<br>', now);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I am sorry, but would you mind writing it in a hastebin/pastebin please? I'm so bad in js ... :/

Answer (score 0):

You can get a random timezone by picking off a random element from all timezones.

```
var all = moment.tz.names();
var randomTimeZone = all[Math.floor(Math.random()*all.length)];
// Use it in the code as
moment.tz(randomTimeZone).format('lll');
```